# joystick getting stuck if you press 2 joysticks at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in which there are 2 joysticks 1 for movement 2 for shooting, so joystick 2 starts to stick if you hold down 2 joysticks at the same time. I tried to fix it by changing speed of each joystick but nothing happened its still here. I dont know what to do so Here is the code

```
namespace GeekGame.Input{

    public class JoystickFire : MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
    {

        public static JoystickFire instance=null;

        private bool _fire=false;
        public bool Fire{
            get{return _fire;}
        }

        void Awake(){
            if(instance!=null){
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            } else {
                instance=this;
            }
        }

        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data){
                _fire=true;
        }

        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data){
            _fire=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably this line:

```
public static JoystickFire instance=null;
```

Any time you declare something static, it means "there will be only 1".  Which is probably not what you want when there are 2 joysticks.